# Safe to use setuid with absolutely no input?

Tags: linux, http, shellcode

I have a shell script which syncs some files from a remote source and I have a pretty typical HTTP server set-up. There is a user who owns the files served by the HTTP server and a user which runs the HTTP server - both of which belong to the same group.

I want the synced files to be owned by the "owner" user and I don't want the HTTP server user to be able to write to them. However, I want the HTTP server user to be able to invoke the sync script.

One option is to wrap the shell script in a small C application and use setuid so the HTTP server user can run it as the "owner" user.

Given that:

- There will be no input to the script - the remote location, destination location, etc. are all constant.
- The setuid script won't be owned/run by root.

Is this a safe and sensible thing to do?

Edit:

For the sake of explaining things you can use the following names:

- deploy-user: The user who should own the files
- www-user: The user running the HTTP server
- www-group: The group deploy-user and www-user belong to
- sync.sh: The script which updates the file
- sync.txt: The target file

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I believe the easiest solution is:

```
chgrp <user> /path/to/syncfile
```

All of what you are trying to do can be accomplished with [chmod](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html), [chgroup](http://ss64.com/bash/chgrp.html), or chown.
(*not enough rep to hyperlink >2 times)

This command above will keep the syncfile owned by owner, while giving group ownership to user.
User group permissions must be set correctly with chmod for this to work. eg.

```
chmod 754 syncfile.foo
```

or

```
chmod 750 syncfile.foo
```

Where 754 gives +rwx to owner, +r-x to file group (user), +r to all others.. 

Or where 750 gives the same, but does not give all others read permissions.

Comment: But how does the www-user invoke the script to update the file? If the www-user invokes the script themselves they won't have permission to write to the file. Basically the www-user should be able to trigger the update but not change what the sync process does or modify the synced file without running the sync process.

Answer (score 1):

(not so)**Complete answer:**

```
#chmod 1770 /directory/containing/syncfile.txts/
#chmod 1750 /directory/containing/syncfile.sh/
#chgrp www-user /path/to/syncfile.sh
```

[chmod](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html)- 
1:Sticky Bit (only owner may delete or modify) 
7:deploy-user +rwx 
7:group users (www-user) +rwx 
0: Everyone else gets no read, write, or execute.
Setting the sticky bit on the second directory is redundant because only the owner will have modify permissions anyway, but why not.

[chgrp](http://ss64.com/bash/chgrp.html)-

Gives www-user syncfile.sh group ownership.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the www-user could still overwrite the content of sync.txt even if they can't delete or move it?

Comment: Incorrect, all files created in the directory with sticky bit set will inherit its permissions. i.e. files can be created by www-user, but once created, not modified.

Comment: Then how will www-data invoke the sync script in future to update the file?